# Bitrix: Trouble while attempting to configure E-Mail SMTP (through Virtual Appliance)

Tags: smtp, bitrix

I ran the **VMware** (as per Bitrix' **[Official Documentation](https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/?COURSE_ID=12&LESSON_ID=4476&LESSON_PATH=3884.5459.4476)**) to configure **E-Mail** SMTP.

But, I ran into a problem as I get **No Options** after logging in:

[image]

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: check VM's config in 'hardware' tab - does it contains network adapter? if yes -could you show result of "ifconfig" command?